# Synonym token filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a test index with synonym token filter

```
 PUT /synonyms-index
{

"settings": {

"analysis": {

"filter": {

"my_synonym_filter": {

"type": "synonym",

"synonyms": [

"shares","equity","stock"

]

}

},

"analyzer": {

"my_synonyms": {

"tokenizer": "standard",

"filter": [

"lowercase",

"my_synonym_filter"

]

}

}

}

}

}
```

Then I ran analyze API ,

```
post synonyms-index/_analyze
{
"analyzer":"my_synonyms",
"text":"equity awesome"
}
```

I got the following response to see what token got into inverted index and I was expecting "shares" and "stock" needed to be added as per the synonym rule, but it doesn't seem so. Am I missing anything here ?

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "equity",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "awesome",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

posting the answer for the community-

it is common pitfall with JSON ,

We need to make it as ( put everything in a double quotes which consistutues a rule and it follows simple expansion.)

```
"synonyms": [ "shares,equity,stock" ]
```

rather than

```
"synonyms": [

"shares","equity","stock"

]
```